# does the function $|\sin(x) |$ define a tempered distribution? if so compute the fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

I need to check if the function $|\sin(x)|$ defines a [tempered distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform) and find  the fourier transform of the distribution.

I think it defines  it because  it is summable on every  compact subset  and I have also found its first  distributional derivative, which is:
$$   f^\prime(x) = \frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{|\sin(x)| } $$
but I am clueless  on how  to find  the $F$ transform.

I  know the for a tempered distribution, if $ \phi $ is a test function then:
$$ \left\langle {\hat T},\phi\right\rangle= \left\langle T,{\hat \phi} \right\rangle $$ and 
$$ \widehat{ D^{\alpha}\phi}   = (i 2 \pi k )^\alpha {\hat \phi}  $$
but I am not able  to use these  rules to complete the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, and quite important thing: if the function is $L^1_{loc}$, it **does not** imply that this function is a tempered distribution. Classic counterexample is $e^x\in L^1_{loc}(\Bbb R)\setminus \mathcal S'(\Bbb R)$.

In your case the straightforward argument that continuous periodic functions define tempered distributions is more than sufficient.

Second, in order to find the Fourier transform, one of possible approaches would be to introduce the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases} \sin x,&x\in[0,\pi ),\\0,&\text{otherwise},\end{cases}$$ and then take $$|\sin x| = \sum _{k\in\Bbb Z}(-1)^kf(x-\pi k).$$

You should be able to find the Fourier transform of $f(x)$ and then use the formula for Fourier transform of a translated function.